# How do I initialize the lattice/grid in a Potts Model?

Tags: model-hamiltonians, monte-carlo, ising-model

I am studying the  [Cellular Potts Model Tutorial](https://artistoo.net/explorables/Explorable-CPM.html).

However, this doesn't say anything about the grid/lattice initialization.

How do I initialize the lattice/grid in a Potts Model?

I.e., how do I assign initial pixel values before running the Monte Carlo loop?

Comment: You can initialize it however you want, there is no correct way to initialize it.
There might be better choices you can make depending on what you want to investigate.

Comment: Cross-posted on Physics.SE https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/723366/49107 by a user of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion [by Erik Kjellgren](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9552/how-do-i-initialize-the-lattice-grid-in-a-potts-model#comment19918_9552):

> "You can initialize it however you want, there is no correct way to initialize it. There might be better choices you can make depending on what you want to investigate."

If Erik or anyone else wants to write up a better answer, this answer can be flagged for deletion.